# Add to an array in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, state

I'm quite new to React and I'm trying to build the classic to do list!  However, I'm struggling to track the array items.
I'm creating the items as follows:

```
     this.setState({item: {
      text: event.target.value,
      index: this.state.items.length++,
      completed:false
        }
```

And I've been adding to the array of items like this:

```
     this.setState({items:this.state.items.concat(this.state.item)});
```

But this method creates a new array every time, so I can't use the index of the item.  However when I try using push to add to the array, I can't seem to display it!  Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What code are you using when you are using `push`?  OR - could you place an id on each item so you don't need positional indexes?

Comment: push would alter the original array, does not return it

Comment: what you mean by "_I can't use the index of the item_"

Comment: I'm not sure how to place an id on the item other than than to base the index on the length of the array!

Comment: well I want to be able to access the items by their position in the list.  Which is what I had the index for, but its not working

Comment: "its not working" - show us the code that's not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I suspect here is when an event to add a task is emitted, you are trying to set a state for `item` and then you are immediately setting the `items` state as well.

> React may batch multiple setState() calls into a single update for performance."

Please refer to the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous). So you shouldn't expect `item` to have your latest item when you try `this.setState({items:this.state.items.concat(this.state.item)});`

You can have try the following

```
const item = [{
  text: event.target.value,
  index: this.state.items.length + 1,
  completed:false
 }]

let items = {this.state}
items = items.push(item)
this.setState({items})
```

You can also pass a function to the setState method

```
this.setState(function(prevState, props) {
   //Code goes here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

By definition, Arrays are immutable data.

To add new item without mutation (and to be most cleaner) exists package [immutability-helper](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper).

Install in the project directory

> npm install immutability-helper --save

...import in the class

```
import update from 'immutability-helper'
```

...and update array

```
update(this.state.items, {
  $splice: [[0, 0, item]]
})
```

This code make a "clone" of total_rating and use the $splice to add the new average at the 0th index.